# How to redo the last command in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

```
#!/bin/bash

function main_menu()
{
echo Simple Linux Utility
echo 0) Repeat last command
read -p "Choose your option : " input

case $input in
    0)
        !!;;
    *)
        exit;;
esac

}
main_menu
exit 0
```

The question is :
"**Simply redo the last command. Use a variable to remember the last number**"
and I **can't write any data to external files**

But I don't know how to repeat last command in shell script
I can't use !! !-1 in shell script, it will show as error

Comment: I think [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147563/how-do-i-repeat-the-last-command-without-using-the-arrow-keys) can help you.

Comment: @ganchito55 unfortunately none of those solutions work for shell scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose such a little solution. 
In the shell function I've added a  loop, so you are able to select the last executed command.

```
function main_menu()
{
    echo Simple Linux Utility
    echo 0: Repeat last command

    while [ true ]
    do
        read -p "Choose your option : " input

        case $input in
            "0") ;;
            "1") cmd="ls -las" ;;
            "2") cmd="uname -a" ;;
             *) exit ;;
        esac

        $cmd
    done
}

main_menu
exit 0
```

Comment: You may want to add the option `read -p "Custom command: " cmd`. I think you will like the built-in `select`.

Comment: I'd recommend `while true; do` or `while :; do`. `while [ true ]; do` works, but so does `while [ false ]; do`, which is counterintuitive if you think `[ true ]` is somehow evaluating a boolean value. Don't mimic other languages when the underlying semantics are completely different.